# About the determinism of the universe and decidability?

Tags: universe, determinism

*Note: I have a math/CS background and only basic knowledge of physics. [Decidability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decidability_(logic)) has to be intended from a logic perspective.*

To the best of my knowledge, we have no proof if the universe is either *deterministic* or *non-deterministic*.

By deterministic I mean it can *theorotically* be fully described through a [deterministic dynamical system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaos_theory). Then, assuming we know that dynamical system, we can *theoretically* fully predict the future.

By non-determistic I mean that we can imagine the universe has to roll a dice every once in a while to decide how to evolve, intuitively speaking.

However, due to [Heisenberg's uncertainty principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_principle), if I understand its implications correctly, for a given time $t$ we cannot know with certainty the state of the universe.
That means, even if the universe may be deterministic, there is no way to learn the dynamical system that describe the universe.
In other words, **1) Even in case of a deterministic universe, we cannot predict the future with certainty**.

Here is the next step, is it even possible to decide if we are in a deterministic or non-deterministic universe?

My guess is that:

- We may theoretically prove *non-determinism* if we had two twin universes and by showing a counterexample in which given the same boundary conditions (at the same time) the two universes evolve in different ways (based on rolling a dice). However, we have no twin universes. There is no way to perfectly replicate an experiment in a single universe, since at least its entropy will change over time. Moreover, there is no way to fully determine the boundary conditions and prove they are the same for two different instants.
- There is no way to prove *determinism* as well since, even if we had the chance to perfectly replicate an experiment in a single universe and we could fully determine the boundary conditions, we cannot show that a certain experiment make the universe *always* evolve the same way exhaustively.

Thus **2) We can neither prove determinism nor non-determinism of the universe**.

Does this make any sense?

Comment: The problem is if my answer is deterministically caused.

Comment: "Does this make any sense?" Not really.

Comment: Might this be a better question for [Philosophy.SE]?

Comment: What do you think about quantum mechanics? It says that every physical measure is not deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

There is an important difference between being uncertain about the state of the universe, and whether the state evolves based only on the current state or on other (random) factors. The first is not determinism, just a limitation on our abilities.

However, you are right that we can never prove or disprove determinism by experiments if we are uncertain about the state *and* update rule. If we could check that the same state did evolve to two different new states we could know the world is indeterministic, and if we knew the update rule we would know the answer straight away. However, even apparently deterministic rules could have weird, rare loopholes making them indeterministic in ways we are unlikely to see.

In practice this is not what physicists care about. They build theories that may be deterministic or indeterministic, and test how well they predict the outcome of experiments. The theory is not reality, just our best current model of what reality does.